# GCM in Swift Bundle ID Error

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging, bundle-identifier

I am having trouble in executing Google Cloud Messaging in Swift. Using `GCMExample` for objective C I am getting the Registration token but when I am trying to run `GCMExampleSwift` which is for Swift I am getting an error. I am using the the same 'GoogleService-Info.plist' for both Objective C and Swift.

> 2015-10-26 17:31:59.834 GcmExampleSwift[360:51727] The configuration
>   file 'GoogleService-Info.plist' is for another bundle identifier
>   ('com.XXXXXX.mobility.appfactory.dev1.social'). Using this file the
>   services may not be configured correctly. To continue with this
>   configuration file, you may change your app's bundle identifier to
>   'com.XXXXXX.mobility.appfactory.dev1.social'. Or you can download a
>   new configuration file that matches your bundle identifier from
>   https:/ 2015-10-26 17:31:59.836 GcmExampleSwift[360:]  App
>   measurement v.1100000 started 2015-10-26 17:31:59.843
>   GcmExampleSwift[360:51727] Successfully configured [CloudMessaging].
>   2015-10-26 17:31:59.843 GcmExampleSwift[360:51727] Failed to configure
>   []. 2015-10-26 17:31:59.843 GcmExampleSwift[360:51727] Subspecs not
>   present, so not configured [Analytics, AdMob, SignIn, AppInvite,
>   Maps]. 2015-10-26 17:31:59.843 GcmExampleSwift[360:51727] Subspecs
>   expected to be present [CloudMessaging, Measurement]. 2015-10-26
>   17:31:59.936 GcmExampleSwift[360:]  Network status has
>   changed. code, status: 2, Connected 2015-10-26 17:31:59.977:
>   GGLInstanceID | Unable to find token in cache Error
>   Domain=com.google.iid Code=-25300 "(null)" Registration to GCM failed
>   with error: The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (com.google.HTTPStatus error 401.) 2015-10-26 17:32:01.053
>   GcmExampleSwift[360:51727]  - changing
>   property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect
>   2015-10-26 17:32:01.053 GcmExampleSwift[360:51727]  - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only
>   layer, will have no effect 2015-10-26 17:32:01.053
>   GcmExampleSwift[360:51727]  - changing
>   property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect

Comment: Seems like the error is complaining about different bundle IDs, are your two projects (Swift and Obj C) using the same bundle ID?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Arthur. The steps provided by ztan worked for me. Made mistake by not changing the individual Bundle ID of the target.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems the Bundle ID in your `GoogleService-Info.plist` does not match the bundle ID in your target.

First you need to add the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file to a correct target, if you are trying the `GcmExampleSwift`, you should select that as the target:

[image]

Then in your `GoogleService-Info.plist` file, if you want to use `com.XXXXXX.mobility.appfactory.dev1.social` as your bundle ID, make sure you spell it correctly in for the `BUNDLE_ID` key:

[image]

Finally, in your targets, make sure you select the `GcmExampleSwift` first (NOT the `GcmExample` which is the Objective - C target), then make the the `Bundle Identifier` matches the `BUNDLE_ID` in your `GoogleService-Info.plist` file:

[image]

Comment: Thank a lot ztan for your answer, it worked. The mistake I was making was changing the Bundle ID for the project but not for the individual target. After changing the Bundle ID for the GCMExampleSwift target it worked.

Comment: The last picture in the answer was my mistake. I didn't select GcmExampleSwift in the TARGETS section (firstly, I wasn't aware if a section like that even existed!). Thank you so much.