# Proper sequence to get registration token for GCM push notification on iOS? Is GCM unreliable?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hi I've followed the tutorial for using GCM on iOS. It has been working intermittently(which means all the certificates, permissions and stuff is okay). However of late, I have been getting the two error messages repeatedly:

`GCM | GCM registration is not ready with auth credentials`.

Also, reconnection to GCM fails with:

`Error Domain=com.google.gcm Code=501 "(null)"`

This co-relates,in part, to the device not getting a GCM registration ID. Has anyone else come across these issues more frequently of late? Or is it because I'm calling the GCM API in an incorrect sequence (especially the `connectWithHandler:`, `startWithConfig:` and `tokenWithAuthorizedEntity` methods)? I suspect that the reason is the latter since I *do* get a GCM ID after some delay.

I do not always receive a GCM ID either. When I don't receive one, I usually have to run the app once or twice more via Xcode. (Or by force-closing the app). Clearly this is not something that my users should have to do.

This is the sequence of my GCM API calls:

1. The device gets an APNS token
2. I then call
   `tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:` by using my APNS token
3. ^ This usually
   results in one of those two errors mentioned above.
4. Whenever I
   actually need a GCM token, I force a refetch of the GCM token by
   calling `tokenWithAuthorizedEntity` again.

Also, I have the `connectWithHandler:` call written inside my `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method also.

**A couple of questions:**

1. Is the call to `connectWithHandler:` in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` necessary if I am only interested in receiving GCM push messages and *not* send them upstream?
2. If answer to (1) is yes, in the completion handler of that method, if an error occurs, and I do not have the GCM token at that point, should I try to get a token again? (i.e. call `tokenWithAuthorizedEntity`?)
3. When should the `startWithConfig` be called? Before getting a GCM token or after?

**EDIT:** Limited testing revealed that the following appears to work:

1. Get the GGLInstance ID first (i.e. call `getIDWithHandler:`)
2. If the above GGLInstance ID was received without any error, ask for a GCM token (i.e. call `tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:`)
3. Doing this generally gives the following error, but at least in a short while(~3-10 seconds), the token *is* received:

> Unable to find token in cache Error Domain=com.google.iid Code=-25300
>   "(null)"

Comment: I am using GCM with iOS as i think it makes things pretty simple. although i havent come across these errors. Post your registration code and i will compare with mine

Comment: if you have followed the GCM example from google you cant really go wrong, id look at the certificates you are using and make sure these are correct for the auth credentials error.

Comment: What auth cred error? If there had been a certificate error, the push would never had worked in the first place.

Comment: For the errors above I'd suggest you implement retry mechanism as suggested in docs and if the issue doesn't go away report this to one of the support channels. See description of 5xx error here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes.

Answer (score 4):

> Is the call to connectWithHandler: in applicationDidBecomeActive:
>        necessary if I am only interested in receiving GCM push messages and
>        not send them upstream?

Yes, [connectWithHandler](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/api/gcm/interface_g_c_m_service#aedac7a5c46f60219563397373e4d71ba) is necessary regardless as its prime purpose is to make connection with GCM endpoint.

> If answer to (1) is yes, in the completion handler of that method, if
>   an error occurs, and I do not have the GCM token at that point, should
>   I try to get a token again? (i.e. call tokenWithAuthorizedEntity?)

So the way it should work is you check for errors while you are requesting the token itself and retry with exponential back-off if the request fails. More info [here](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/ios-implementation#generate_a_token). Also, read the note [here](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/ios/api/interface_g_g_l_instance_i_d#aff40184a34dd68f4df23a9a34da83240). Now, if you still want to re-invoke the `GGLInstanceIDTokenHandler` at any point you should also implement `deleteTokenWithAuthorizedEntity` before getting a new token.

> When should the startWithConfig be called? Before getting a GCM token
>   or after?

In your `AppDelegate.m` you should invoke the `GGLInstanceID` shared instance using `startWithConfig` method. Essentially in `GGLINstanceID.h` class, it should first get an Instance ID; then authorize the project as Authorized Entity and then get a Registration Token through the iid service. See the detailed implementation for `GGLInstanceID.h` class [here](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/ios-implementation).

Hope this answers help!

**EDIT**

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361326/gcm-in-swift-bundle-id-error?answertab=votes#tab-top) answer your question? Gist of it is, make sure the Bundle Identifier for your target is the same as the BUNDLE_ID in the info.plist file.

Hopefully this resolves the error, if not post what happened when you test it and we can go from there. :)

Comment: Do you mean to say that these things should be in strict sequence?:

1) Get GGLInstance ID (via `getIDWithHandler:`)
2) Then call `tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:`?
(which means I'd have to call (2) in (1)'s completion handler only if i successfully get the Instance ID in (1))

Comment: I am not too sure about the strictness of the order but by logic GGLInstanceID is must before you can fetch a token since this Token is generated through the Instance ID service and unless the app instance initializes this Instance ID, how is it supposed to assign a token?

Comment: With regards to TokenWithAuthorizedIdentity; I can't comment with surety about where it should fall but AFAIK the project auth is also important before the Token is retrieved by the device.

Comment: In summary, acco to my understanding: the Registration Token would have such Auth credential which corresponds to the App Instance for a specific Project on a specific device. Note here that, it is imperative for GCM to identify "xyz" Project on an "abc" device for the "1st" instance of the app; so that it can deliver the notification to its exact destination. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Okay yes that makes sense. I'll keep testing it meanwhile and report back here.

Comment: Well, during my limited testing, asking for the token *after* successfully getting the GCM ID seems to work (although there is still a delay of ~ 3-10 seconds)

Comment: Nope, I have double-checked that I have the same Bundle ID in both my target and my GoogleService-Info.plist. The same cache miss error occurs

Comment: Provisioning profile, APNS pem cert and .p12 for GCM cert - all these are properly generated? With GCM on iOS, the initial set up can be tricky but is important. Also, make sure the credentials in the Xcode project matches ones in the Google Developers Console. If all this seems properly configured, you should contact Google support through one of the support channels I linked in one of the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Try move the connectWithHandler block to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, after you get the gcmConfig block.(for official's example, after the [END start_gcm_service])