# iOS GCM Fails to connect after some time

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, keychain

I have implemented Google Cloud Messaging in my app. The app registers without problems. But after a day or two it can not connect anymore to google's MSC. The app uses a Dev Provisioning Certificate and is running with `kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true`.

I have added the debugging flag `-GMRDebugEnabled`. It says it is missing auth credentials in my keychain.

```
GCM | No cached checkin auth credentials in Keychain.
GCM | Cannot find checkin plist contents.
GCM | No cached checkin auth credentials in Keychain.
GCM | Cannot find checkin plist contents.
GCM | GCM registration is not ready with auth credentials
GCM | No cached checkin auth credentials in Keychain.
GCM | Cannot find checkin plist contents.
GCM | Failed to connect to MCS. No deviceID and secret found.
GCM | Did start network rechability notifications
```

The error object which comes with the connection handler is empty.

```
Domain=com.google.gcm Code=501 "(null)"
```

Also it shouldn't be a networking issue since I try to connect via mobile network. Anyone has a clue why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

It is an internal error based from Google documentation.

> Errors in the 500-599 range (such as 500 or 503) indicate that there was an internal error in the GCM connection server while trying to process the request, or that the server is temporarily unavailable (for example, because of timeouts). Sender must retry later, honoring any Retry-After header included in the response. Application servers must implement exponential back-off.

Try to refresh your registration token and see if it works.

Comment: What do you mean with "refresh your token"? Refreshing Token is triggered by GCM Server - not by the iOS app. When I try to re-register it works - but is this desired behaviour?

Comment: It seems that the error occurred because you were calling `GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler() { error in  if(error != nil) {   print(error) } }` before you had received a registration token.

Comment: I already have received a registration token - at initial app start. As I described above - somehow it gets invalidated. In the documentation - there is a separate handler for refreshing a token - triggered by the GCM Server - but it doesn't get called.

Comment: Maybe this link will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918922/proper-sequence-to-get-registration-token-for-gcm-push-notification-on-ios-is-g