# unable to find token in cache error GCM iOS

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to configure GCM in iOS. I have followed all the steps and created all the certificates required for push notifications. While registering for push notifications, device token is returned which is forwarded to google server. However, registration token returns nil with error

```
Unable to find token in cache Error Domain=com.google.iid Code=-25300 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.iid error -25300.)
```

This was working initially, but suddenly stopped working. I haven't changed any p12 files or certificates.

Comment: Have you tried looking to this Stack overflow ticket? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361326/gcm-in-swift-bundle-id-error).  Also, use this as your guide: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client. I hope it might help you.

Comment: I have the same error, you solved the problem?..

Comment: Even i have the same problem. Was anyone able to solve this

Comment: If you have configured the APNs certificates and other provisioning profiles correctly, this problem won't occur. In our case, the problem was something related to provisioning profiles. Cross checking all certificates should rectify.

Comment: @AnonymousRacer: Could you please give us more details? I'm facing the same issue and I don't have a clue what might be. I've re-created the APNs certificates & provisioning profile. Anyway, I've created [a issue on their repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/205).

Answer (score 2):

I got this issue because the time on my phone was set in the future, once the time was set correctly the problem was resolved.

Initialy I had the problem discussed under: [why didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086599/why-didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-is-not-called)

After following the instructions there, which required to reset the time I finally got the didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken to work but then I was getting this issues. Once the time was set back to normal everything start working.