# Ionic ios push: Unable to find token in cache Error Domain=com.google.iid Code=-25300 "(null)"

Tags: ios, push-notification, ionic-framework

I'm trying to set the push notifications for ios, i'm working with ionic and phonegap-push-plugin.

This is the conf:

```
var conf = {
        android: {
          senderID: "********************",
          "icon": "icon",
          "iconColor": "black"
        },
        ios: {
          gcmSandbox: true,
          senderID: "********************",
          alert: "true",
          badge: false,
          sound: 'false'
        },
        windows: {}
      };
```

And I have the next error on my iphone 5:

```
2016-02-29 23:42:48.351 MDZOL[466:82778] active
2016-02-29 23:42:48.352 MDZOL[466:82778] PushPlugin skip clear badge
2016-02-29 23:42:48.696 MDZOL[466:82778] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2016-02-29 23:42:51.292 MDZOL[466:82778] Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CFB8C8D3-FD5D-4710-A1FA-7480F82708D0/MDZOL.app/www/index.html#/tab/home
2016-02-29 23:42:51.820 MDZOL[466:82778] Ionic Core: plugins are ready
2016-02-29 23:42:51.829 MDZOL[466:82820] Push Plugin register called
2016-02-29 23:42:51.829 MDZOL[466:82820] PushPlugin.register: setting badge to false
2016-02-29 23:42:51.829 MDZOL[466:82820] PushPlugin.register: clear badge is set to 0
2016-02-29 23:42:51.830 MDZOL[466:82820] PushPlugin.register: better button setup
2016-02-29 23:42:51.830 MDZOL[466:82820] GCM Sender ID **************
2016-02-29 23:42:51.830 MDZOL[466:82820] Using GCM Notification
2016-02-29 23:42:51.831 MDZOL[466:82820] Using GCM Sandbox
2016-02-29 23:42:51.845 MDZOL[466:82778] Push Plugin register success: <dc52fb00 0aac3a80 7eac3d06 aeae102c ef905958 512c9252 937c6f7e dee26593>
2016-02-29 23:42:51.977: GGLInstanceID | Unable to find token in cache Error Domain=com.google.iid Code=-25300 "(null)"
2016-02-29 23:42:52.788 MDZOL[466:82778] Registration to GCM failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 401.)
2016-02-29 23:42:53.412 MDZOL[466:82778] Error
2016-02-29 23:42:53.413 MDZOL[466:82778] {"line":57,"column":54,"sourceURL":"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CFB8C8D3-FD5D-4710-A1FA-7480F82708D0/MDZOL.app/www/plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/www/push.js"}
```

I don't use swift so, this stack isnt for my problem: [GCM in Swift Bundle ID Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361326/gcm-in-swift-bundle-id-error)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem, and I solved it by adding the .p12 files to GCM with this magic link: https://developers.google.com/mobile/add